# Handsontable formulas at column level and syncing

Tags: handsontable

we have a handsontable based sheet .. built on top of Reactjs+Immutablejs actually.

This spreadsheet has a simple usecase :

1. compute some values when you are editing/adding the sheet.
2. sync the data to server
3. when you get new data from server - dont compute,
   just take the data as it is . Server is authoritative.

Currently, I'm doing this by hardcoded javascript functions in afterChange hook. Because I'm simply not able to figure out how to do these three things using Handsontable rulejs.

Q1. a rulejs formula is of type "=A1+B1". I have 500 rows in my sheet  - how can I create these formulas on a column level ? It seems I have to hand create 500 formulas for a single column.

Q2. How do I stop formula from being applied when I get data from server ? Or rather, I dont care if formulas are applied, I still want to use the data from the server. Is there a hook for afterFormulaComputed or something that I can use to override ?

Q3. silly question - how do I get the computed value of a cell and not the formula itself. I found "hot.plugin.helper.cellValue" on Stackoverflow somewhere, but was not able to figure it out. Especially because my code uses row and column ids to do stuff rather than "A1" or "C1"

any help would be highly appreciated !

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but how do you use handsontable with ReactJS?